# Which 3-manifolds have positive rank gradient?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, 3-manifolds

> For which $3$-manifolds $M$ is the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$
>   finitely generated and has positive rank gradient?

Recall that the rank gradient of a finitely generated group $G$ is defined to be $$\inf_{H} \frac{d(H) - 1}{[G : H]}$$ where the infimum is taken over all finite index subgroups $H$ of $G$, and $d(H)$ stands for the minimal cardinality of a generating set of $H$.

Comment: Well, any virtually fibred 3-manifold must have zero rank-gradient, so that doesn't leave too many possibilities.

Comment: @HJRW right! I knew this. So I want to know in which cases the rank gradient is known to be $ > 0$. Is there some exact meaning in "too many possibilities" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is answered in the proof of Theorem 8.5 of [this paper](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/faculty/files/virtualspecialICM.pdf). This
says that the rank gradient is zero iff $M$ is prime or $\mathbb{RP}^3\#\mathbb{RP}^3$.

**Edit:** There's a small step missing from the argument. The argument shows that if $G$ is an orientable connected sum 3-manifold group (not $\mathbb{RP}^3\#\mathbb{RP}^3$), then there exists $G' \lhd G$ of finite index so that $G'$ has positive corank gradient, hence positive rank gradient. Since $d(G')-1\leq [G:G'](d(G)-1)$, if $G$ has rank gradient $0$, so would $G'$ a contradiction (one applies this inequality to $G'\cap H \lhd H$). This applies as well to non-orientable 3-manifolds, where one has to consider the $\mathbb{RP}^2$-decomposition, or just posit that there is a prime cover.

Comment: You assume that $M$ is closed and orientable. What about the general case?

Comment: @Pablo: see my revision.

Comment: So, the only way to get a $3$-manifold whose fundamental group has positive rank gradient is to take a connected sum of $3$-manifolds not both $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3$?

Comment: Correct, in the orientable case.

Comment: And what nonorientable examples exist?

Comment: For non-orientable manifolds, one has to consider the $\mathbb{RP}^2$ decomposition. So, for example, if a hyperbolic 3-manifold $M$ admits an orientation-reversing isometry with two fixed points, the quotient will be an oribfold with two point which are cones over $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Remove neighborhoods of these and glue the $\mathbb{RP}^2$'s together. This manifold has orientable double cover $M\# (S^2\times S^1)$, so has positive rank gradient. You can imagine generalizations of this. See: http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s3-11/1/469

Comment: Is it true that in these cases the fundamental group is a free product amalgamating $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2$)?

Comment: @Pablo: correct

Comment: Dear Ian, thank you for this illuminating discussion. I am asking a more general question now: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223747/rank-gradient-in-free-products-amalgamating-a-finite-subgroup