# Rank gradient in free products amalgamating a finite subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, geometric-group-theory, free-groups

Let $A,B$ be finitely generated groups with a common **finite** subgroup $C$. Suppose that $[A : C] > 2, [B : C] > 1$.

> Must $A *_C B$ have positive rank gradient?

See [Which 3-manifolds have positive rank gradient?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223715/which-3-manifolds-have-positive-rank-gradient/223737#223737) for a definiton of rank gradient.

The assumption on the index is necessary (otherwise we take $A,B = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, C = \{1\}$).

The case $C = \{1\}$ has been established by Marc Lackenby - Proposition 3.2 of http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lackenby/er190804.pdf

I think that there should be a proof using Bass-Serre theory, at least in the case that $A,B$ are residually finite. The argument is as follows:

Since $A,B$ are residually finite, $G = A *_C B$ is residually finite as well. It is enough to show that the rank of normal subgroups $N$ of finite index in $G$ grows linearly with the index $[G : N]$. Residual finiteness, allows us to take $N$ to be disjoint from $C$ in $G$. From Bass-Serre theory, one can hopefully write $G$ as a free product with amalgamation (since $N$ does not meet any conjugate of $C$ in $G$) and calculate its rank.

Comment: You should make a residual finiteness assumption to avoid trivial counterexamples (and also assume explicitly the implicit $[B:C]>1$). Also please give a definition, or link to another post, for the definition of rank gradient.

Comment: @YCor - I have referenced a definition. I do not see which counterexamples arise if either $A$ or $B$ (or both) are not residually finite. Furthermore, I think that it is sufficient to assume only that $[A : C] > 2$ and not also $[B : C] > 2$. In the absence of residual finiteness, the resulting free product with amalgamation may have no finite index subgroups at all, but in this case, the rank gradient is positive by definition.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ both have no nontrivial finite quotient, then $A\ast B$ has no nontrivial finite quotient as well, so the rank gradient is zero.

Comment: @YCor this is the point I was trying to make in my previous comment. If the only finite quotient is trivial, then the rank gradient is just $d(A *_C B) - 1$ which is positive.

Comment: OK thanks for the correction, you're right. If $M$ is an infinite f.g. group with no nontrivial finite quotient and $K$ has order 2, do you know what the rank gradient of $K\ast (K\times M)$ is?

Comment: @YCor The rank gradient of this group is positive - this follows from the result of Lackenby which I have cited in my question...

Comment: Sorry indeed I was misled by my intuition. From what I can read a few lines before Question 1.10 here (http://people.virginia.edu/~mve2x/Research/ershov-lueck120826.pdf), I'd expect that for groups with positive first $\ell^2$-Betti number, the rank gradient is positive. This would answer positively your question.

Comment: @YCor you are right! But, can you show that the first $L^2$-Betti number is positive?

Comment: @YCor this probably follows from Proposition 3.1 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.4327v2.pdf

Comment: This follows (assuming $A$ and $B$ are residually finite) exactly as in the referenced proof to my previous question. More generally, it holds when $C$ is separable in $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @IanAgol this is true in general - see my previous comment.

Comment: Actually I had no doubt about the fact that fg groups with infinitely many ends have positive first $\ell^2$ Betti number, but the fact that fg groups with positive first $\ell^2$ Betti number have positive rank gradient is not exactly what is stated in the reference I gave. I guess it's known anyway.

Comment: @YCor which examples of groups with infinitely many ends are there?

Comment: @Pablo, a (fg) group with infinitely many ends is precisely a group which splits over a finite group and is not virtually cyclic.  This is a famous theorem of Stallings.